# Opening modal on screen change in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, use-effect

As title says, I want to open modal every time I enter a screen, I'm using `useRoute` hook to get route name, and I'm passing it as a dependency in `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setModalOpened(true);
  console.log('reload');
}, [route.name]);
```

Here is JSX code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.head} />
  {isModal ? (
    <Modal
      isVisible={modalOpened}
      backdropColor="transparent"
      onBackdropPress={() => {
        navigation.goBack();
        setModalOpened(false);
      }}
      style={[
        styles.modal,
        {
          top: height,
        },
      ]}>
      {children}
    </Modal>
  ) : (
    <View>{children}</View>
  )}
</View>
```

Seems like it doesn't call the hook, the route name must be changed otherwise it wouldn't navigate to other screen.

Comment: Is `isModal` what is set by `setModalOpened`? If not then the modal won’t even render let alone set visibility.

Comment: No, it's passed as prop and it doesn't change. It's layout component.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at some scenarios:

**`Firstly,`**

- If you pass empty parameter as the second parameter to `useEffect` then it will run once when the component is mounted and your code will be like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Your code here
}, []);
```

**`Secondly,`**

- If you don't pass any parameter as the second parameter to `useEffect` then it will run on every render of the component and your code will be like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Your code here
});
```

**`Thirdly,`**

- If you pass any parameter as the second parameter to `useEffect` then it will run when the component is mounted and if your parameter changes it will run on every change of your parameter. In this case, your code will be like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // Your code here
},[props.someName]); // Only re-run if props.someName changes]);
```

So if you would like to see your modal on every time you enter into your component, then it can be achieved by implementing the second case.

Hope it will help.

**Note: The second case can be dangerous, so use it carefully.**

Comment: I understand all cases, even without dependencies nothing happens.

Comment: So, you want to see the modal when you enter from a different route, don't you?

Comment: Since it's not working, so it's hard to say by seeing this code only that what's wrong with your code. It would be better if you provide some extra information for better understanding.